# How to scroll to the beginning of the scrollview in react natvie

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native. I want to do something like this.
I have horizontal scrollView and it has several tabs. So when the user press on a tab a i want the scrollview scroll to the beginning of the tabs (to first tab).So how can i do that using scrollTo() method.

```
    <ScrollView horizontal showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} >
              <FilterTab>
                  <Block fluid>
                    <P>
                      TAB 1
                    </P>
                  </Block>
                </FilterTab>
                 <FilterTab>
                  <Block fluid>
                    <P>
                      TAB 2
                    </P>
                  </Block>
                </FilterTab>
                <FilterTab>
                  <Block fluid>
                    <P>
                      TAB 3
                    </P>
                  </Block>
                </FilterTab>
                 <FilterTab>
                  <Block fluid>
                    <P>
                      TAB 4
                    </P>
                  </Block>
                </FilterTab>

      </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via the use of a `ref`, and the `scrollTo()` method:

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {

  /*
  With the ref added below, you can call scrollTo() on the scrollview
  via the _myScrollView ref, as follows:
  */
  scrollToTop() {
    this.refs._myScrollView.scrollTo(0);
  }

  render() {

    /* add the _myScrollView ref to your scroll view component */
    return (
      <ScrollView ref='_myScrollView' horizontal 
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} >
        <FilterTab>
            <Block fluid>
              <P>
                TAB 1
              </P>
            </Block>
          </FilterTab>
            <FilterTab>
            <Block fluid>
              <P>
                TAB 2
              </P>
            </Block>
          </FilterTab>
          <FilterTab>
            <Block fluid>
              <P>
                TAB 3
              </P>
            </Block>
          </FilterTab>
            <FilterTab>
            <Block fluid>
              <P>
                TAB 4
              </P>
            </Block>
          </FilterTab>
        </ScrollView>)
  }

}
```